# Connect Handheld with Emulator wearable AVD

Tags: android, dependencies

I have a problem to connect my Handheld with my Emulator wearable AVD.
I try to display a new notification in my smartphone and in my wear in the same time.
But when I start my application on my smartphone, and I click on my button, I have the notification that appears but nothing on my wear. (I think it's maybe a dependencies error....).

I will go to explain what I have doing :

- I have create a new emulator wearale AVD. It works on the API 21.
- I have join my handheld with my wear with :     ./adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601
- I create a new project :

my build.gradle :

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca3koza"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

my Manifeste.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

my MyActivity.java

```
    package com.enterprisemobility.michael.ca3koza;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
    import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class MyActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    Button wearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wearButton);
    wearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int notificationId = 001;

            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                            .setContentTitle("Title")
                            .setContentText("Android Wear Notification");

            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                    NotificationManagerCompat.from(MyActivity.this);

            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    });

}
}
```

my acitvity_my.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyActivity">
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Notify Wearable"
    android:id="@+id/wearButton"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Thank you very much for your help can I can't understand why my wearable doesn't display the notification.

P.S : When I use the Demo Cards with the wear app on my smartphone, my wearable displays the notification like the sports, or the bourse for example.

Mickey74

Comment: Nobody to help me ???